# calling functions without copying into script window

Tags: r, function

The default library for my R installation is 
`C:\Users\mmstat\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\`

I also have functions with .txt extensions saved in a second folder 
`c:\S library\`

My problem is that I don't know how to tell R about my function library 'S library' so I don't have to copy and paste the code for the wanted function in my script window and then executing it.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can source the files or if they are broken up, source those file in particular. You may have to change the extension to .R. Also, if you want to load these functions for every session, there are post on SO for how to do this in your profile.

Comment: You could also use `sourceDirectory` from `Rutils` to source everything in a directory. You can add a pattern filter as well. That being said, the cleaner option would be to package you functions in.. a package.

Comment: Interesting. I will try sourceDirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give the simplest base-R answer:

```
fList <- list.files(path="c:/S library/",pattern="*.txt")
lapply(fList,source)
```

Answer (score 1):

NB: I don't have windows so the paths might need some editing to works properly on your own system.

NB 2: you might need to change the extension of the files from .txt to .R

if you want to create/use it as a package, you can give a try to the [modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules) package. It was built with python users in mind.

If you are using these functions frequently, I would recommend adding a variable to your .Rprofile as well (for Unix-based system it is usually: ~/.Rprofile, no idea for windows)

```
import.path='c:/S library/' #Based on Ben Bolker recommendation
```

If you don't want or can't modify your profile, you can also do it from within R (but you would need to do it everytime).

And then in R:

```
#only the first time and if you want to update later on.
require(devtools) ## you will need to install it if you don't have it already
devtools::install_github('klmr/modules')
```

And then everytime you want to use it, it would be something as the following:

```
library(modules)
options(import.path="c:\\S library\\")
Slib=import('nameOftextFile')#example myFun

and then you can use it:

foo=Slib$myFun(arg1,arg2,)
```

Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/klmr/modules) for a better explanation.

Comment: backslashes in Windows paths need to be doubled/protected (`import.path="c:\\S library\\")` (but easier just to use forward slashes, which R understands).  I don't see why you would need to change the extension ...

Comment: Thanks. All comments were really helpful

Comment: @BenBolker True, you probably won't need to change the extensions, I just suggest it since a while ago I had a problem with an import function because of the extensions of my files. (I can't remember what was the library though).